# bootstrap form while mobile

Tags: html, css, twitter-bootstrap

I'm using a form for the site search with a button inside the text-box. On the desktop version it works ok, howerver when resizing to mobile it is not. I am using a position: absolute; to set the button positioning, giving it a fixed position. Is there any way I can make this work on the mobile version as well?

HTML:

```
    <!-- Right search form -->
    <div class="col-md-3 col-xs-12">
      <form class="form-inline" role="search">
        <div class="form-group">
          <input type="text" class="form-control search-input" size="40" placeholder="Cauta in site...">
          <input type="submit" value="" class="search-button" id="searchsubmit">
        </div>
      </form>
    </div>
```

CSS:

```
.search-button {
background: url('../images/search-btn.png') right no-repeat;
border: 0px solid black;
border-left: none;
cursor: pointer;
height: 35px;
width: 35px;
position:absolute;
left:241px;
top: 3px;
}
```

Answer (score 2):

you can use the bootstrap class 
[reference here](http://getbootstrap.com/components/#input-groups-buttons)

```
 <div class="input-group">
  <span class="input-group-btn">
    <button class="btn btn-default" type="button">Go!</button>
  </span>
  <input type="text" placeholder="Cauta in site..." class="form-control">
</div><!-- /input-group -->
```